# how to make pipe in for cycle in second section?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, pipe

My question is how to make this work?

```
FOR /F %pam IN ('echo show databases; ^| mysql -ubackup -h33.33.33.33 -pmysecrethaha') DO (mysqldump --add-drop-database -C --lock-all-tables -pmysecrethaha -ubackup -h33.33.33.33 %pam% | C:\Program0x20Files\7-Zip\7z.exe a -si -bd G:\mysql\redmine\%today%\%pam%.7z)
```

This command should make dump of each db in separate files, but I get this error:

```
"a was unexpected at this time."
```

what do you think?

Comment: Make sure your database names do not contain spaces. Otherwise use double quotes around occurrences of the loop variable or around the expressions it's included in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I would like to say that is one LONG line of command  lol.

Secondly, for safe measure, start you FOR loop as:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%a IN (`echo show databases; ^| mysql -ubackup -h33.33.33.33 -pmysecrethaha`)
```

Just make a habit of using the USEBACKQ option, and place your command in back-quotes... just in case you ever have to use quotation marks in a command line argument or file paths with spaces inside of this FOR /F command loop.

Thirdly, as PA stated, use single letters for your temporary variable in a FOR loop (a-z OR A-Z case sensitive  e.g. %%a OR %%A)

Then anytime you call that variable, you just reference it as is e.g. if the variable is %%a you call it with %%a.

Answer (score 1):

Change %pam% to %%a; and put the command inside the loop in a new line, the pipe should work perfectly.

Use this test batch as a sample

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('dir /b /od *.txt') DO (
  type %%a | more
)
```